# Accepting a calendar invite without being invited when organizer is from G-Suite

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, rfc5545

I'm trying to accept an invite to a calendar event without being invited to the event, according to the [rfc5546](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.2.6) this is legal, when I do so when the organizer is from Office, accepting the invite without being officially invited by the organizer works fine but when doing so when the organizer is from G-Suite this does not work and Gmail writes: "xxx is not invited to this event. xxxx has accepted this event."  and does not add the "party crasher" to the event.
This is the ICS file I use in order to crash the uninvited event:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//app//ES
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REPLY
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20210307T171500Z
DTEND:20210307T181500Z
DTSTAMP:20210307T153404Z
ORGANIZER;CN=xxxx@gmail.com:xxx@gmail.com
UID:xxxxx@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=xxx@acme;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:xxxx@acme
CREATED:20210307T150458Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20210307T153401Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Testing 34
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Comment: It is "legal" but it depends on a number of things, including whether Google or the Domain with the account want to allow this. Can you detail the reproduction steps? Can you confirm all the [sharing options](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60765?hl=en#zippy=) of the calendar that makes the invitation? Does the responder send the right type of response according to the rfc5545? Also this may be applicable - https://support.google.com/a/answer/6329284?hl=en

Comment: Check out https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/172013 - as Google Groups may be more suited to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi thanks for you comments. Regarding your questions. The sharing options are OK as I try to do this with a private account at the moment and there is no restrictions there at the moment. The response I send back is like the ICS file that I posted above just with the fields that are aligned with the event. Google groups is not a good options for me at the moment as I don't know in advance who will "crash" the event.

Comment: And regarding the steps to reproduction. I create a calendar event and then I try to accept it programmatically by sending a ICS file like the one I posted above just with the event's details. As far as I know it is "rfc5545" complaint.

Comment: Can you please add in detailed steps for reproduction into your original question? "I try to accept it programatically" could mean so many different methods. The idea is that you may have found some bug, and if you have a way to reproduce it, then you should share the details - see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm just trying to solve this exact problem (teaching Emacs/Gnus how to reply to accept an ical event where one is not invited) but without success with Google Calendar.  Party crasher do not seem supported.  Similarly, replying by mail to an invitation sent from a secondary calendar (where the organizer email has the form `*@group.calendar.google.com`) does not work even from some expected attendee (only the embedded HTML link works).